# Jetpack Navigation Graph with Notification and Nested multiple graphs Issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

**I have one Activity which has the Navigation Host Fragment.I have multiple nested graphs. The Flow As Follows :**

Main Navigation Graph contains the Splash Screen From where we are deciding that if user is logged in then we are redirecting to the Dashboard Graph and If user is not logged in then we are redirecting to the Login Graph.

Dashboard Graph has Bottom Navigation View and here my question come in to picture that if I am sending the Notification for Bottom Navigation View Third Tab. So How can i call that fragment.

Because Currently My App is in foreground with first tab, if i received the notification  for third tab then also it loads the Splash Graph and came to First tab same if App is in Background or killed.

How can i manage this Scenario Please Suggest.

> Below Is my code for Sending the Notification with Pending Intent:

```
 var args = Bundle()
    if (!clickAction.isNullOrEmpty() && clickAction.equals("More")) {
        args.putString("click_action", clickAction)
        args.putString("userId", userId)
        deeplink = NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.dashboard_graph)
            .setDestination(R.id.fragmentMore)
            .setArguments(args)
            .createPendingIntent()
        Log.e("Deep Lin---k", "More")
    }
```

> Dashboard Navigation Graph is as following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
    android:name="com.appname.structure.dashabord.ui.FragmentProfile"
    android:label="@string/label_profile"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile">


</fragment>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentChangePassword"
    android:name="com.appname.structure.user.ui.FragmentChangePassword"
    android:label="@string/label_change_password"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_change_password" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentMore"
    android:name="com.appname.structure.dashabord.ui.FragmentMore"
    android:label="@string/label_more"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_more">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_move_to_change_password"
        app:destination="@id/fragmentChangePassword"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/pull_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/push_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/pull_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/push_out_right" />


    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_move_to_login_dashboard"
        app:destination="@+id/user_graph"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/pull_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/push_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/pull_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/push_out_right"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/fragmentMore"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_move_to_cms_dashbaord"
        app:destination="@id/cmsFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/pull_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/push_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/pull_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/push_out_right" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_move_to_change_language"
        app:destination="@id/languageFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/pull_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/push_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/pull_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/push_out_right" />


</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/cmsFragment"
    android:name="com.appname.structure.cmspage.FragmentCMSPage"
    android:label=""
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_cms">
    <deepLink
        android:id="@+id/deepLink"
        app:uri="https://navigation.tutorial/{cms-url}/{cms-title}" />
</fragment>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentStore"
    android:name="com.appname.structure.dashabord.ui.FragmentStore"
    android:label="FragmentStore" />


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/languageFragment"
    android:name="com.appname.structure.dashabord.ui.FragmentChangeLanguage"
    android:label="@string/label_change_language"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_change_language" />
</navigation>
```

Please Check and Provide best support based on the your experience..